# I'm new to d3, is there a simple way?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I'm completely new to d3. I've been developing for a few years, but I managed to track down d3 after seeing this great little tool in action.
http://gia.guim.co.uk/2013/03/video-game-violence/index.html

The problem is, from what I've found so far, d3 definitely doesn't have the same following as jquery. The documentation and the tutorials just aren't there as much.

I'm unfamiliar with SVG, but it looks pretty decently usable.

I wanted to reach out and see if anyone has some a hello world for this specific example?

I'd like to start with two sets of data and show the connections between them, but this feels like a decently large operation to just jump right into.

Comment: http://www.jeromecukier.net/blog/2013/03/05/d3-tutorial-at-strata-redux/ is my favorite intro. There are lots of others: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tutorials and plenty of getting started examples: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery#basic-charts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check Scott Murray's tutorials [here](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/).

They were even converted to a book "Interactive Data Visualization".

Comment: Agreed, these tutorials will get you started. The book doesn't add much though, but could be handy if you like reading.

Comment: I just went through the tutorials, these really do give you a pretty solid jump on d3. Thanks!!